# Angular: Nested route with default

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a page (which is already in a `router-output`) on the route /products. The page itself does have another `router-output` which will have 2 possible children (/products/professional and /products/consumer).

When a user visits /products (without nested route), I want them to be routed to /products/professional.

This is my routes setup:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsComponent, // this component includes `router-outlet` for the child routes as they share the same header
    redirectTo: '/professional', // won't work!
    children: [
      {
        path: 'professional',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('...').then((c) => c.AComponent)
      },
      {
        path: 'consumer',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('...').then((c) => c.BComponent)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Obviously, I can't use `redirectTo` and `children` for the same route. It will throw this error:

```
Error: NG04014: Invalid configuration of route '{path: "products/", redirectTo: "professional"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'.
```

I have seen similar questions (and their respective answers) but I bring my brain to adjust these answers to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `redirectTo` as a separate object

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'professional', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Complete example will look like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // add this new route object here.
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'professional', pathMatch: 'full' },

  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'professional',
        loadComponent: () => import('...').then((c) => c.AComponent)
      },
      {
        path: 'consumer',
        loadComponent: () => import('...').then((c) => c.BComponent)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: That does work, thank you. Although it doesn't really make "declarative sense"?!